# Vertical upright text in safari has tiny spaces

Tags: html, css, safari

When using `writing-mode: vertical-lr` with `text-orientation: upright`, all characters are about the same height. However, on Safari, the space character between words becomes very small. Here is a code snippet for demonstration:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Asap&display=swap");
span {
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
  text-orientation: upright;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  -webkit-text-orientation: upright;
}
```

```html
<span>Hello, World!</span>
```

On Chrome and Firefox it looks like this:

[image: Vertical "Hello, World!" text with the space selected.]

On Safari, however, it looks like this:

[image: Vertical "Hello, World!" text with the space selected. The space character is tiny.]

What would be the best way to make the space character the same size on all browsers that works with multiple fonts and font sizes?

Comment: white-space, line-height, have you tried to reset those to a fixed value ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus white-space doesn't affect the space size it seems, and neither does line-height. line-height actually seems to change the horizontal spacing between vertical lines of vertical text

Comment: It might be because of the default CSS styling on every browser, try reset these values using this https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ And then put your own styling so it will be consistent on every browser you use.

Comment: @MarLMazo just tried that. thanks for the link! didn't seem to work, though

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, instead of using `text-orientation: upright;` try just rotating the text using `transform: rotate(90deg);`

```
span {
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Then target specific browsers:

```
span {
  font-family: Asap, sans-serif;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Here is an example in a snippet -

```css
span {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<span>Hello, World!</span>
```

Comment: that snippet is the same code as in the question, and the css above the snippet creates vertical text, yes, but then the characters are *sideways*, not upright

Comment: Corrected the snippet but I see the problem with the characters being sideways, you might need to check if Safari browser supports  text-orientation and writing-mode

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: I filed [this bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=260120) in the hope that it will be fixed in the future.

I recently came across this issue and couldn't find anything about it on the web.

But I've found a sort of **hacky solution** that seems to render equal spacing in all major browsers (tested in Chrome, Firefox and Safari). I know the solution I'm going to provide is not ideal, but for now it's the only thing that fixed the problem.

The solution is to add `<span>` elements with whitespace characters such as `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space char) within the vertical upright text element. Set the height of these added `<span>` elements to a fixed value that fits your design and font. Note that you need to set the `display` property to `inline-block` for the height to work.

[Check out this CodePen with the solution provided](https://codepen.io/glmvc/pen/YzRPoaX)